# Linux Mint default partitioning: Useful for System Reinstallation?

Tags: linux-mint, partition, system-installation, hard-disk, distribution-choice

When you install Linux Mint OS, you are offered to build one partition for both system and user files.

```
LVM VG mint-vg, LV root as ext4
LVM VG mint-vg, LV swap_1 as Swap
Partition 1 on SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) as ESP
```

After the installation is finished, and you check the setup in gParted, you see this information:

```
/dev/sda1  EFI System Partition  fat32    /boot/efi  (boot,esp)
/dev/sda2  --------------------  ext4     /boot       
/dev/sda3  --------------------  lvm2 pv  mint-vg
```

So, where can I find the root directory "/" ? 
And what if one day I need to replace this operating system with a different Linux distribution? Would I not be forced to harm my personal files? If so, then why is this partition setup offered by default?

EDIT: [I thankfully got the hint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/569239/184608) to open the terminal and type in "sudo lvs", in order to see, what the third (physical) partition "mint-vg" consist of. The output tells that the physical partition "mint-vg" contains two "logical volumes" (LV), which are root (/) and swap.

```
  LV     VG      Attr       
  root   mint-vg -wi-ao----                                                 
  swap_1 mint-vg -wi-ao----
```

OK, this brings me to the next question:
Why does gparted not show the logical volumes? Is it because the parental physical partition is encrypted through the Linux-Mint installation tool? **After this, I am still afraid, that my data in /home will be lost, if I try to reinstall the operation system.**

Comment: usually "root" is a partition besides of "boot", "swap" and "home" - for example sda5 in this screenshot: http://refugeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Ubuntu-Only.png

Comment: gparted does not support LVM logical volumes. There's no evidence showing that you are using block device encryption. As for reinstalling, there's no subsitute for making backups of important information.

Answer (score 1):

You disk `/dev/sda` has three partitions, however your third partion is an LVM physical volume. This physical volume is divided into one or more logical volumes, one of which is your root filesystem; `/`. You can run the command `lvs` to see which logical volumes you have.

As for harm caused to your files if you replace your Linux distro, it depends. Often times you can instruct the installer which devices to partition and format. For example, assuming the "system files" are installed in a separate logical volume than the "user files", you can have the installer format the "system" logical volume and leave the "user" logical volume alone.

Comment: Thank you very much. This brings up another question. I am going to update my main question above, accordingly.